# Swag hooks in drywall ceiling, steel frame house

Tags: hanging

I want to hang some Moroccan decór lanterns. Would swag hooks work? The house has a steel frame, so I can't use a stud. It would be just drywall. I'm not sure the total weight of all the lanterns together. They're probably 1-2lbs, if that, and I have about 5 with a few hanging candle holders (tea light). One I think is heavier though. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The hook that you are using is not the issue - how it is secured in the dry wall is. I am guessing your lanterns are probably 4 lbs - you can check by standing on a scale with a lantern and then getting on the scale with out the lantern and subtract, the difference will be the lantern weight.

Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0792Y4SGB) should do it, you will notice the grip mechanism that fits above the drywall - screw in type swags do not have the necessary grip and weight distribution to hold that kind of weight and also handle the lantern being touched or moved.

*If you perform a search you might look for Toggle Wings or Toggle Bolts.*
Added above to the answer per comments. 6-19-2018

[https://www.amazon.com/BBTO-Totally-Ceiling-Hardware-Installation/dp/B0792Y4SGB/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1522997013&sr=1-1&keywords=BBTO-Totally-Ceiling-Hardware-Installation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0792Y4SGB)